# XPath findelement по 2 параметрам

Tags: xpath

Нужно с помощью xpath выбрать нужный radio элемент, но это можно в моем случае сделать только если выбрать одновременно 2 параметра: `name` и `value`.

Так работает выбор по `name`:

```
el = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@name='aiosp_rewrite_titles']"));
```

Как сюда же вписать выбор по `value = 0`?

Answer (score 1):

Добавить `and @value='0'`.

`el = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@name='aiosp_rewrite_titles' and @value='0']"));`

Answer (score 0):

либо добавить `[@value = '0']`

```
el = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@name = 'aiosp_rewrite_titles'][@value = '0']"));
```